# Servlet and resource URL clash in Servlet API

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a servlet

```java
@WebServlet(name = "ToDoServlet", urlPatterns = "/*")
public class ToDoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ToDoServlet.class);

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("PathInfo: {}", req.getPathInfo());

        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/templates/index.jsp")
                           .forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

In `web.xml` I have only error page definition.

If I go to the URL `http://localhost:8080/webappname/` I got 404 error in browser and this in the server log:

```
17:05:58,540 INFO  [ru.geekbrains.controller.ToDoServlet] (default task-1) PathInfo: /
17:05:58,543 INFO  [ru.geekbrains.controller.ToDoServlet] (default task-1) PathInfo: /WEB-INF/templates/index.jsp
17:05:58,545 INFO  [ru.geekbrains.controller.ToDoServlet] (default task-1) PathInfo: /WEB-INF/error.jsp
```

But if I change servlet mapping to `\something\*` it works.

It looks like a path clash between resources in the war file and registered servlets.

Is that true? How to resolve that?

P.S. I deploy the application to the Wildfly 17.0.1.Final

Comment: The browser could not access the files within the WEB-INF folder. you should move your jsp pages next to that folder and not within.

Comment: I want to make this page available only through the request to the servlet. That's why it's inside `WEB-INF` folder.  That's Ok to forward requests to files in this folder with `RequestDispatcher`.

Comment: Just change the urlPatterns = "/*" to urlPatterns = "/" which means your servlet will not serve every request under the / but only those that matches with your root url http://localhost:8080/webappname/ it should help I think

Comment: It work with "/" pattern but I don't understand why. This pattern explained in Server API specification as 'default' servel override. Is that good idea to override the default Servlet?

Comment: It depends. If there is no resources to server (images, css, js files, etc.) maybe. The jsps complied to servlets btw, but they could not get the request until your controller servlet catches everything (As /* suggests)